# ServiceStack EventLog Always prints "An error occurred in the application:"

Tags: logging, servicestack

always when I use the eventlog there is a string printed before my content "An error occurred in the application: "

Why? What should I change?

For example this code:

```
 var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

    logger.Info("AppHost up and running");
```

Ends in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is built into ServiceStack's [Event Logger Adapter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.EventLog/EventLogger.cs).

You can use your own copy of it and configure it how you wish, or you could submit a pull-request to make the error message configurable in the EventLogger.

Comment: Ah ok so it is as designed and not a bug or a mistake i made :-) right?